# Sustained SPI communication FT232H

Tags: usb, spi, ftdi, performance

**Background**

I am using FT232H to communicate with my peripheral using the libMPSSE provided by FTDI. I am aware of the INFRA_SLEEP(2) issue with SPI_ToggleCS() function. My peripheral requires me to send in a CS toggle right after each 24-bits of data being sent to it. I have 40 such words of 24-bits that needs to be sent to the peripheral.

I require to update the 40 words at a rate of 4KHz, which means I need to send 40x24-bit words every 0.25 milliseconds. This implies:

1. I need to toggle the CS pin 40 times every 0.25ms => 160/ms => 160,000 toggle/second.
2. I need to send 40x24-bit data every 0.25ms => 960bits/0.25ms => 3840bits/ms => 3.84 Mbits/second.

3.84 MHz (SPI) is the theoretical sustained minimum requirement for my use case. Since 1Mbit/sec => 1MHz in SPI and the theoretical max of FT232H is 30MHz, I need about 12% of the limits of FT232H. I technically don't need sustained 3.84 Mhz, I can zoom at 30Mhz, sleep for 0.25ms (up to), and then go at 30Mhz, is this not possible with FT232H?

**Implementation**

In order to overcome the SPI_ToggleCS()'s sleep issues, I have packed the data efficiently to FT_Channel_Write directly. All the commands are right, I inspected the FT_Channel_Write calls and captured the transactions to effectively come up with what to send to FT_Channel_Write. This part works. My pack size to FT_Channel_Write is 40x writes, which includes 24bits of payload and 40 CS toggles in that. Then my main loop sleeps for 0.250ms before waking up and sending the next payload.

[image: SPI Performance]

**Problem**

After sending roughly 3150 K-bits of data via SPI no matter how fast or slow I send it, the FT232H seems to stall (no further data is sent till restarting my code). I have sent in different packet sizes, different delays, and a lot of combinations but. This seems to be the magical number I am hitting. 3135K to 3157 K-bits. Maybe there is some variance from testing.

**Questions**

1. What could be the issue here?
2. Is there a buffer size limit I should be aware of? (I did pour over the datasheet and couldn't find anything around this number)
3. What approaches would you suggest that I take to try to debug and find the root cause of this issue?

Comment: "A single call to FT_Write can actually contain a number of MPSSE commands and arguments." is the key idea I have been using based on https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_135_MPSSE_Basics.pdf

Comment: Maybe you are limited by an (input) buffer? Are you aware of FT_SetUSBParameters ( https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Knowledgebase/index.html?ft_setusbparameters.htm ) ?